# Installing ffmpeg in Ubuntu by using Chef fails by error of yasm version

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, chef-infra

I want to install `ffmpeg` in Ubuntu14.04 by using `chef`.

This is my config files for it.

#### Berksfile

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"
cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'ffmpeg'
```

#### nodes/ubuntu.json

```
{
    "run_list": [
        "apt",
        "ffmpeg"
    ]
}
```

Then run `knife solo cook ubuntu`. It ends up with a error:

```
STDOUT: Found no assembler
Minimum version is yasm-1.2.0
```

I understand the error. probably if I install `yasm-1.2.0` manually, then the error will be fixed.

But I want to install only by using `chef`. What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ffmpeg` cookbook isn't installing a required dependency to build ffpmeg from source. You can either install from packages or report a bug over [on the cookbook's GitHub page](https://github.com/escapestudios-cookbooks/ffmpeg/issues). Unfortunately due to poor coding, the only way to set the install mode to packages is to make a wrapper cookbook, you can't use roles or other sources of node attributes.

As I'm guessing you are new to Chef, I would recommend either writing your own (much simpler) cookbook. All you need in a recipe is:

```
package 'ffmpeg'
```